# CSS Div Alignment Problems

Tags: css, html, alignment

I've been trying to help my friend complete their small website and really struggling, I've lost through the site and experimented with different bits of CSS but just got myself stuck and would really appreciate any help! Basically the site is sitting here

```
http://213.229.123.200/~conceptp/test/
```

I've been trying to re-arranging the divs through the source and CSS so get everything positioned so it sits like this example screenshot

```
http://213.229.123.200/~conceptp/test/example.jpg
```

I'm using a form on the left and will be displaying some text and video in the div on the right hand side.

Also just getting the footer to be relative to where the page ends rather than fixed position isn't going right either hence the gap in footer :/

I'm sure it will be simple to somebody who knows how but I'm stuck and would welcome any help!

Thank you

Chris

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your links to screenshot not even clickable.. and apart from that it is not easy to provide solution without code.

Comment: you want to look into using css `float` for your div positioning and perhaps google css sticky footer for your footer problems

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm your question is too broad, but from quickly looking at it,  you need to use position relative and absoulte more.

Also around the contact form and information, you need to fix the html something like this to pur them right next to each other

```
<div class="informationContactContainer">
    <div id="contactForm" style="float: left; width:50%">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="information" style="float: left; width:50%">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and use absolute position on the class .prev and .next
something like

```
position: absolute; 
top: -10px;
```